# Chrome Extension PopUp Button not Functioning

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently creating a chrome extension for dyslexia and am trying to link a button press in the popup for the extension to changing the font size of the page as an initial step, but I'm having trouble making it work. The issue is that nothing happens upon pressing the button in the pop up.

Here is the html for the pop up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        button {
          height: 30px;
          width: 30px;
          outline: none;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<button id="changeFont"></button>
 <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here is the source file for the popup html:

```
 let changeFont = document.getElementById('changeFont');
changeFont.onclick = function(element) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code:
    'var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');'+ 
    'for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {'   +
    'var element = elements[i];' +
        'element.style.fontSize = "50px";'+
        '}'
                 });
      };
```

Last, here is the manifest file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Dyslexipro",
    "description": "dyslexia aid ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["activeTab",
        "tabs","declarativeContent","storage"],
    "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
      }

    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },
   "background": {
       "scripts": ["content.js","popup.js"],
      "persistent": true
    }
}
```

Comment: First line of the injected code has a `*` that is not inside the string. Also you can right click the extension in the toolbar to inspect its popup and debug the problems there.

Comment: @PredatorIWD Thank you! That solved my problem. I wasn't aware of that tool and I'll use that in the future to troubleshoot more effectively.